# Joomla 3.2 K2 2.6.7 Using Wrong Item Alias From Category View

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla3.1, joomla3.2

In the process of designing a new template for my employers site, I have set up a separate menu and assigned a the new template to that menu. I also made sure to assign the old template to the old menu so there was no confusion. Well...we have confusion. The problem I am having is that now with the new menu in place, the old menu/template is giving the wrong url alias when viewing an item from a categories blog layout. So for example:

old menu/template url looks like this

categories view:

```
mydomain.com/local-news/sports/
```

should point to:

```
mydomain.com/local-news/sports/4622-article-1
```

instead points to:

```
mydomain.com/new-sports/item/4622-article-1
```

In old-menu parent/childs looks like this

```
local-news
|_sports
|_|_city-1
|_|_city-2
|_|_city-3
```

In the new menu sports is a menu root item and looks like this

```
sports
|_city-1
|_city-2
|_city-3
```

My K2 Categories are set as follows:

```
local-news
|_sports
|_|_city-1
|_|_city-2
|_|_city-3
```

I'm a little bit of a stranger to K2, so what am I possibly doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your problem, but it looks like a confusion with menus and/or k2 sef parameters. What's your current category view url ? mydomain.com/new-sports ?

Comment: I solved this on my own. Apparently Joomla will default to the most recent menu ID & alias for any particular item view, and ignore the menu alias, when viewing an item from within the same domain. So my work around for this behavior was to setup a subdomain, and install and configure the virtual domains plugin. This worked, but I still dont think I understand the reasoning of this behavior by joomla. It should adhere to the menu alias'